# How to handle '\' in json date with python json.loads

Tags: json, python-3.x

I want to read texts from a json file and then convert it to a python dict object, but meet some problems when the backslash is in the json data.

---

what my json file is like:

```
{
    "foo": "+|\\*|/",
}
```

I want to get a dict like this:

```py
{
    "foo": "+|\*|/",
}
```

but I get this actually:

```py
{
    "foo": "+|\\*|/",
}
```

---

If I change the json file like this:

```
{
    "foo": "+|\*|/"
}
```

or

```
{
    "foo": "+|\\\*|/",
}
```

then I will get an error.

The python versoin is 3.8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be not in the loading of the JSON file, but in displaying its content as Python object (since `repr()` is used under the hood, and returns the representation with single quotes and escaped characters).

For example, my file (named 1.json) is

```
{
    "foo": "+|\\*|/"
}
```

I'm using the following code to load it in Python 3.8.0:

```py
import json
a = json.loads(open("1.json").read())
```

Now `print(a)` prints `{'foo': '+|\\*|/'}`, while `print(a["foo"])` will print the correct result: `+|\*|/`.

So, please check that your displayed part is *not* using `repr()`.